# Trouble while modifying a pointer within a C function

Tags: c, list, pointers

Hi I'm trying to implement a liked llist operation in C. My approach is to implement all operation in a header C file, and to include it in a main file to manage linked lists.

Here is the header file `linkedlist.h`, containing operations implementations

```
//Here is my code for the node structure:

struct node {
  struct node * next;
  char cinfo;
};


//Here is a method to do a simple insertion in the begining of the list

 void beginInsertSL(char val, struct node ** root){    
  struct node *p = malloc(sizeof(struct node*));
  p->cinfo = val;

  if(*root == NULL){
    p->next = NULL;
  } else {
    p->next = *root;
  }

  *root = p;
};

//Here is a method to do many insertions

void beginInsertSLN(char *ch, struct node **root){
  root  = malloc(sizeof(struct node**));

  int size, i;

  size = strlen(ch);
  i = 0;

  if(size > 0){
    while(i < size){
      beginInsertSL(ch[i], root);
      printSL(*root);
      i++;
    }
  } else *root = NULL;
}

//And finally a method to print a list, to be able to see 

void printSL(struct node *root){
   struct node *p;

  if(root == NULL) printf("[ ]\n");
  else {
    p = root;

    printf("[ %c", p->cinfo);

    while(p->next != NULL) {p = p->next; printf("->%c", p->cinfo);}

    printf(" ]\n");
  }
}
```

Here is the main function to use those methods

```
#include "linkedlist.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

   // declaring the root of my linkedlist
   struct node **root = NULL;

   if(argc > 0){
     // inserting char in the linked list
     beginInsertSLN(argv[1], root);

     // print the linked list to see the result
     printSL(*root);
   }
}
```

When executing this code, I get the following result :

```
./lltest stackoverflow
[ s ]
[ t->s ]
[ a->t->s ]
[ c->a->t->s ]
[ k->c->a->t->s ]
[ o->k->c->a->t->s ]
[ v->o->k->c->a->t->s ]
[ e->v->o->k->c->a->t->s ]
[ r->e->v->o->k->c->a->t->s ]
[ f->r->e->v->o->k->c->a->t->s ]
[ l->f->r->e->v->o->k->c->a->t->s ]
[ o->l->f->r->e->v->o->k->c->a->t->s ]
[ w->o->l->f->r->e->v->o->k->c->a->t->s ]
Erreur de segmentation (core dumped)
```

Can some one help me to understand what I'm missing here ?

Comment: When declaring your root I think you  just want a single *. E.g struct node *root = NULL  then pass the address with & e.g. beginInsertSLN (argv [1], &root)

Comment: And then lose the * when calling prints I. E. printSL(root)

Comment: This line: struct node *p = malloc(sizeof(struct node*)); and similar lines.  the code needs to malloc the size of a node, not the size of a pointer to a node. so the line should be: struct node *p = malloc(sizeof(struct node));  And the code should always check the returned value from malloc to assure the operation was successful

Comment: `struct node *p = malloc(sizeof(struct node*));` --> `struct node *p = malloc(sizeof *p);` is easy to code, maintain and what is needed here: the size of the structure, not the size of a pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a mess with pointers in your code

Try the following. Take only into account that I did not split the program into modules and used an explicitly specified string. You may remove it or uncomment the string definition in main for testing the program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//Here is my code for the node structure:
struct node 
{
    struct node *next;
    char cinfo;
};


//Here is a method to do a simple insertion in the begining of the list

void beginInsertSL( struct node **root, char c )
{    
    struct node *p = malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );
    p->cinfo = c;
    p->next = *root;

    *root = p;
}

void printSL( struct node *root );

//Here is a method to do many insertions

void beginInsertSLN( struct node **root, const char *s  )
{
    while ( *s )
    {
        beginInsertSL( root, *s++ );
        printSL( *root );
    }
}

//Here is a method to print a list, to be able to see 

void printSL( struct node *root )
{
    if ( root == NULL ) 
    {
        printf( "[ ]\n" );
        return;
    }

    printf( "[ %c", root->cinfo );

    while( ( root = root->next ) != NULL ) 
    {
        printf( "->%c", root->cinfo );
    }

    printf(" ]\n");
}

//And finally a method to clear the list 

void clear( struct node **root )
{
    while ( *root )
    {
        struct node *tmp = *root;
        *root = ( *root )->next;
        free( tmp );
    }
}    

int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    struct node *root = NULL;

    if ( argc > 1 ) beginInsertSLN( &root, argv[1] );

//    char *s = "stackoverflow";
//    beginInsertSLN( &root, s );

    printSL( root );

    clear( &root );

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
[ s ]
[ t->s ]
[ a->t->s ]
[ c->a->t->s ]
[ k->c->a->t->s ]
[ o->k->c->a->t->s ]
[ v->o->k->c->a->t->s ]
[ e->v->o->k->c->a->t->s ]
[ r->e->v->o->k->c->a->t->s ]
[ f->r->e->v->o->k->c->a->t->s ]
[ l->f->r->e->v->o->k->c->a->t->s ]
[ o->l->f->r->e->v->o->k->c->a->t->s ]
[ w->o->l->f->r->e->v->o->k->c->a->t->s ]
[ w->o->l->f->r->e->v->o->k->c->a->t->s ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's reduce your code to the first bug that I found:

```
void beginInsertSLN(char *ch, struct node **root){
    root = malloc(sizeof(struct node**));
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
   struct node **root = NULL;
   beginInsertSLN("stackoverflow", root);

   assert(root == NULL);
}
```

Note that given this code, `root` will remain equal to `NULL`. Which is certainly not what you intended.

You probably want something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct node {
    struct node * next;
    char cinfo;
};

void beginInsertSL(char val, struct node **root){
    struct node *p = malloc(sizeof *p);
    p->cinfo = val;
    p->next = *root;

    *root = p;
}

void beginInsertSLN(char *str, struct node **root){
    int i;
    for (int i=0; i<strlen(str); ++i)
        beginInsertSL(str[i], root);
}

void printSL(struct node *root){
    if(root == NULL) {
        printf("[ ]\n");
        return;
    }

    struct node *p = root;
    printf("[ %c", p->cinfo);
    while(p->next != NULL) {
        p = p->next;
        printf("->%c", p->cinfo);
    }
    printf(" ]\n");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    struct node *root = NULL;

    beginInsertSLN("stackoverflow", &root);
    printSL(root);
}
```

Also, it's worth calling this one other bug out explicitly:

```
struct node *p = malloc(sizeof(struct node*));
```

You're allocating the wrong amount of space! It should be `malloc(sizeof(struct node))`.

Answer (score 1):

You are modifying a local copy of `root` in `beginInsertSLN`. It doesn't change the value of `root` in `main`.

This should work:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

   // declaring the root of my linkedlist
   struct node *root = NULL;
           //  ^^ Use node *root, not node **root

   if(argc > 0){
     // inserting char in the linked list
     beginInsertSLN(argv[1], &root);
                          // ^^ Pass the address of root, not root.

     // print the linked list to see the result
     printSL(root);
   }
}
```

Comment: this line: if(argc > 0){  argc will ALWAYS be greater than 0.  it will always be (at least) 1, because the first entry in argv[] is always the path/name of the file being executed.

Comment: @user3629249 The C11 spec says "The value of argc shall be nonnegative" and "If the value of argc is greater than zero, ..." §5.1.2.2.2 2.  Suggest that non-hosted environments may use `argc == 0`. "it will always be (at least) 1" is a typical observation, but not a spec.  IAC, code should be `if(argc > 1) {` here.