# C, linked list: show every int

Tags: c, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I've looked for an answer but every time I ended up not fixing my code.
I have a struct:

```
struct node { 
  int x;
  struct node * next;
};
```

I don't have any head/tail.
I want to display every "x" of my list.
Suppose I've already managed to make a list from user input.
Here's my code (not working):

```
void printlist(struct node * l)
{
    struct node *tmp = l;
    while (tmp)
    {
        printf("%d\n", tmp->x);
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
}
```

My program just doesn't show anything; returns 0 and exists.

EDIT: to answer your comments:

```
typedef struct node * Node;
void add_top(Node l, int x)
{
    Node newHead = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    newHead->x = x;
    newHead->next = l;
    l = newHead;
}

void add_bot(Node l, int x)
{
    Node tmp = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    tmp = l;

    while (tmp)
        tmp = tmp->next;

    Node newTail = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    newTail->x = x;
    newTail->next = NULL;
    tmp = newTail;
}
```

While, in main():

```
    int x, keep = 1;
    Node l = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    l = NULL;

    while (keep && scanf("%d", &x))
        if (x == 0)
            keep = 0;
        else if (x % 2 == 0 && x > 0)
            add_top(l, x);
        else if (x % 2 == 1 && x > 0)
            add_bot(l, x);
```

Comment: Your program for displaying the data is perfectly valid. If it does not show anything, you are to blame the part that adds nodes to the list.

Comment: did you use a debugger?

Comment: Can you show how you build the list?

Comment: How do you send the node* variable into printlist() function? Are you sure it's not null? How do you keep track of your list without head/tail ?

Comment: "I don't have any head/tail" - then what are you passing to `printlist()`, and how did you acquire *that* (whatever it is) ?

Comment: If your program is not even printing garbage, you might have called as `printlist(NULL)`.

Comment: In `add_top()` the statement `l = newHead;` does not alter the node passed. It alters the variable local to the function. as @vlad says.

Answer (score 1):

Function `printlist` is correct. As for your problem then it means that `l` is equal to `NULL`.
You should analyze your code where you add new nodes to the list.

There are many questions about linked list here. So you can see many realizations of the single linked kist. For example today I already answered [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27363991/trouble-while-modifying-a-pointer-within-a-c-function/27364230#27364230)

EDIT: After you showed other code of your list then I can point out that already function `add_top` is wrong. It should look like

```
typedef struct node * Node;

void add_top( Node *l, int x )
{
    Node newHead = malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );
    newHead->x = x;
    newHead->next = *l;
    *l = newHead;
}
```

Similarly function `add_bot` is wrong. Try update it yourself.

In main you have to substitute these statements

```
Node l = malloc(sizeof(Node));
l = NULL;
```

for

```
Node l = NULL;
```

Otherwise you have a senseless memory leak.

And the condition in the while loop is wrong.

Instead of

```
while (keep && scanf("%d", &x))
```

there should be

```
while (keep && scanf("%d", &x) == 1 )
```

Comment: @Edward  You have to pass the pointer by reference. Otherwise the original value of the pointer will not be changed in the functions. The functions will change a copy of the pointer.

Comment: `== 1` is unnecessary.

Comment: @Karoly Horvath The funtion can return EOF. In this case the condition will be true.

Comment: @Karoly well, I could also do !() instead of ==0... that's just more readable